# Symbology Collector app with related tables

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, symbology, relates, arcgis-collector

I’m trying to make a collector layer with related tables. The symbology of feature class must be someting like:  if {relatedtable.waarnemingen}date + 30 = Current_date() green dot, else red dot.

I found this video on google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzNJTb5E_Mk where a guy explains exactly  what I need, but he doesn’t show how.

I created a feature class(peilbuizen) with point features.
It looks like this:

- OBJECTID
- List item
- PeilbuisID   short
- GlobalID
- Status   text

I also created a table(waarneming) where I store my monthly data.
It looks like this:

- OBJECTID
- Date date
- lenght   dubble
- PeilbuisID   short

Relationship class looks like this:

- Name: REL1
- Origin object class: Peilbuizen
- Destination object class: Waarneming
- Type: Composite
- Forward Path Label: Waarneming
- Backward Path Label: Peilbuizen
- Message propagation: Forward (origin to destination)
- Cardinality: 1 - M
- Has attributes: No
- Origin Primary Key: PeilbuisID
- Origin Foreign Key: PeilbuisID

Can someone explain to me what I must do so symbology of feature layer changes when there something changes in related table?

Comment: What is happening when two records in related table different on change at tribute?

Comment: does not work, tried